# After update angular version 8 to 11, app is not running

Tags: router-outlet, angular11

I have an Angular app version update from 8 to 11. This router is not working after the update. Show blank page when application is run. There is no error in the compilation and browser consoles. How to solve the problem?

```
export const AppRoutes : Routes = [
{ path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent }
{ path: '', component: MainComponent},
{ path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
    { path: 'test-one', loadChildren: () => import('./TestOne/TestOne.module').then(m => m.TestOneModule)},
    { path: 'test-two', loadChildren: () => import('./TestTwo/TestTwo.module').then(m => m.TestTwoModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard], runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'}
]},
{ path: ':pageslug', component : MainComponent },
{ path: '**', component : MainComponent }
```

];

Comment: Hi try to add router debugging as per this post - can help.
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016858/angular-9-routes-giving-blank-pages-with-no-errors>

Comment: @VikramJhurry I am try this but its not working. Same problem still.

Answer (score 0):

There are some breaking changes concerning router in Angular 11 as follows:

> router: * The initialNavigation property for the options in RouterModule.forRoot no longer supports legacy_disabled, legacy_enabled, true, or false as valid values. legacy_enabled (the old default) is instead enabledNonBlocking
> enabled is deprecated as a valid value for the RouterModule.forRoot initialNavigation option. enabledBlocking has been introduced to replace it
> router: preserveQueryParams has been removed, use queryParamsHandling=”preserve” instead
> router: If you were accessing the RouterLink values of queryParams, fragment or queryParamsHandling you might need to relax the typing to also accept undefined and null. (#39151)

Pls see :
https://medium.com/swlh/angular-11-in-depth-9a7372b4a600