# I cant navigate to the index page, when i click back button in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have Angular project. on the index page I have buttons, which drives me in another page. when I want to go back on index page, I click back button of browser and then comes just a white page, not my index page. did u have same issue ?

Comment: It appears to be an issue related to Angular Routing and Browser History. It would be helpful if you refer to the guide for the [angular navigate to previous page](https://nils-mehlhorn.de/posts/angular-navigate-back-previous-page).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not an issue with angular routing. I would suggest checking that the routing is configured correctly.

Assuming that you have set up angular routing in your project ([this](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)), you have to ensure that the route for your index page is registered correctly. In your `app-routing.module.ts` there should be something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'another-page', component: AnotherPageComponent },
  { path: '', component: IndexPageComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
]
```

In your `app.module.ts`, ensure that the `BrowserModule` and the `AppRoutingModule` have been imported.

If angular routing is configured correctly, you could maybe enable route debugging to find the problem. Other answers suggest that this might be helpful ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62025299/6395114), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669041/6395114)).

Comment: First of all, thanks for time. I have this code
`const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent },
{ path: 'hotels', component: HotelsComponent },
// i tried to add this, but it doesnot work
{ path: '/', redirectTo: '/' },];`

Comment: @Irakli ah, there we go. There is a problem in your code: replace `path: '/'` with `path: ''` (similar to my example) and I am confident that it will work.

Comment: thanks , but i already solved this issue with another method

Comment: no problem. I suggest editing your question to let others know what your solution was, as well as marking the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with following:
I gave my index page (app.component.html) class "mainPage"

```
<div class="mainPage" #mainPage>
... // index page
</div>
```

Then I wrote following code in app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('mainPage') buttons!: ElementRef;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef, private router: Router){
      
    router.events.subscribe((eve : any )=>{
        this.currentRoute = router.url;
        if(this.currentRoute == '/'){
          this.showIndex();
        } 
      });
  }
  
  currentRoute : string = "";\
ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  hideIndex(){
    this.renderer.addClass(this.buttons.nativeElement, "d-none");
  }
  showIndex(){
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.buttons.nativeElement, "d-none");
  }
  title = '';
}
```